# How to setup testing environment for rxjs-v5?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

The official doc just give a short example for it.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/observables/interval-spec.ts

This official testing setup to much thing.

I need a simple example so that I can start to write the unit test for my `rxjs` app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The right way to test rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779910/the-right-way-to-test-rxjs)